# Phrasing Specflow scenarios

Tags: specflow

I have written a lot of steps that cause me to get confused between  the Arrange and Assert steps in my code.

For example:

```
given file A exists
when I rename it 
then file B exists
```

The arrange part of my code should be making a file and the Assert part of my code should be testing for the existance of a file

however because both steps translate as "File X Exists"  I keep getting confused and writing assert code in my arrange steps.

How can I phrase things better so that I don't get confused ?

I have thought of using the present tense in the Arrange part of the specflow
For example

```
given I make file A
```

However the human readable aspect doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your given and your then you are expressing a different intent.  `File A exists` is very concise but not really great for communicating with other people.

There are many ways of writing cucumber.  For me, the thing I think about when phrasing "THEN" parts is "what should have happened" - "should" is the important word to me.

How about

```
Given a file named "0001.mpg" exists
When I rename "0001.mpg" to "dance competition finals.mpg"
Then a file named "dance competition finals.mpg" should exist
```

Grammatically:

- `Given ... exists` - is in the simple present tense - i.e. this is true now, and isn't conditional on anything.
- `Then ... should exist` expresses neccessity in the present tense - i.e. if you check right now this instant, then it ought to be so.  ("should" is a "deontic" modal verb according to [english stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/65240))